# SharePoint Search C# with Keyword Query Filter based on Search Keyword and Content Type

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I am trying to do a SharePoint Search based on a Keyword like "Finance" and then filter the result based on 2 content type.

I am able to search the Site based on the keyword "Finance" but I am not able to figure out where to add the filter queries.

**C# Code:**

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("SITE_URL");
clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext)
{
    QueryText = "Finance",
    RowLimit = 50
};

SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);

ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine("Title");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(resultRow["Title"]);
}
```

**Search Filter from SharePoint Page:**

```
{searchboxquery} Path:{Site.URL}* (ContentTypeID:0x012002* AND CustomArticleAttachment:null) OR ContentTypeID:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D000B78192FF0604947A8C72A5A95B15DD5*  (contentclass:STS_List OR contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary)
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CSOM let's you provide filter instructions in code, but you can create a [SharePoint search scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/understanding-result-sources-for-search) (result source) that will do your filtering before-hand.  Then, reference that search scope in your CSOM.

See [this SE thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135318/sharepoint-define-search-scope-using-csom) for more info.